# How to use dropdownlist selected value in Where clause of Update statement?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

SO I am back with another question this time. After solving the parsing issue I had. I cant seem to upload my datbase with my sql statement which some how looks very wrong to me. I have search the net for 5 days but to no avail.

I want to update the database table. Using the where clause. And the where clause will use the selected Value from the drop down list.

Here are my codings:

Edit.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><meta charset="ISO-8859-1">

<head>
<title>Kinder App - Edit</title>
</head>
<style> body {background-image: url("/KinderApp/images/Untitled-1.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat;}]
  header   {color:black; background-color:white;}
  footer    {color:green; background-color:lightgrey; }
  h1 {font-family:Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive; font-size:50px; }
  h6 {font-family:Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive; font-size:15px; color: red; font-weight:bold; }
  span {font-family:Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive; font-size: 15px; color:blue;  }
  </style>
<link href="general.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<script src="dropzone.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
function display_c(){
var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
}

function display_ct() {
var strcount
var x = new Date()
document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;


tt=display_c();
 }

function showModule(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
    document.getElementById("id").value="";
    return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); 
        {
         for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
          document.getElementById("name").value = data[i].mname;
          document.getElementById("desc").value = data[i].mdesc;
          document.getElementById("icon").value = data[i].micon;
          document.getElementById("vers").value = data[i].mvers;
          document.getElementById("loca").value = data[i].mloca;
         }
        }
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getmodule.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
function editModule(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
    document.getElementById("id").value="";
    return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); 
        {
         for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
          document.getElementById("name").value = data[i].mname;
          document.getElementById("desc").value = data[i].mdesc;
          document.getElementById("icon").value = data[i].micon;
          document.getElementById("vers").value = data[i].mvers;
          document.getElementById("loca").value = data[i].mloca;
         }
        }
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("POST","edit_file.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<body onload=display_ct();>
<center><header>Kinder App</header></center>
<br>
<center><h1>Edit</h1></center>
<br>
<form action="edit_file.php" class="dropzone"><center><h2>Drag and Drop to upload</h2>
<br><h6>WARNING: uploading files with the same file name will oveerwrite the uploaded one.</h6></center></form>

<form action="edit_file.php" method="POST">

<center><table border="1" width="50%">
   <tr>
     <td><center>Module ID:</center></td>
     <td><center>
        <select id="id" name="mID" class="quform-tooltip chosen-select" onchange="showModule(this.value)">";
         <?php 
         define("DB_USER", "root");
         define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
         define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
         define("DB_NAME", "kp2admin");
         //echo '<select name="mID">';
         $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
       $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT Module_ID FROM module ORDER BY Module_ID");
       if ($result != null) {
            echo '<option value="" selected>Select</option>';
            $num_results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            for ($i=0; $i<$num_results; $i++) {
               $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
               $mId = $row['Module_ID'];
                echo '<option value="' .$mId. '">' .$mId. '</option>';
           }
           
              
          //echo '</select>';
       }
       mysqli_close($dbc);
       ?>
       
    </select>
  </center></td>
 </tr>
     
 
<tr>
     <td><center>Module Name:</center></td> 
     <td><center><input type="text" id="name" name="mName"/></center></td></tr>
    <tr>
     <td><center>Description:</center></td>
     <td><center><input type="text" id="desc" name="mDesc"/></center></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><center>Icon:</center></td>
     <td><center><input type="text" id="icon" name="icon"/></center></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><center>Version:</center></td>
     <td><center><input type="text" id="vers" name="mVersion"/></center></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><center>Location:</center></td>
     <td><center><input type="text" id="loca" name="mLocate"/></center></td>
   </tr>
</table>
</center> 
       
        <center><input type="submit" value="Update Details"></center>
</form>
    <p><center><a href="list_modules.php">See all files</a></center></p>
<p align="right"><b><span id='ct' ></span></b></p>
<p id="demo"></p>
<form name="myform" action="KinderAppAdmin.html" method="POST">
<input type="image" src="/KinderApp/images/sds.png" name="image" width="61" height="49">
</form>
<footer><center>Copyright © All Rights Reserved</center></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

edit_file.php:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Kinder App Login - Administrator</title>
</head>
<style>
  body {background-image: url("/KinderApp/images/Untitled-1.png"); background-repeat: no-repeat;}]
  header   {color:black; background-color:white;}
  footer    {color:green; background-color:lightgrey; }
  h1 {font-family:Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive; font-size:50px; }
  span {font-family:Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive; font-size: 15px; color:blue;  }
  div {font-family:Comic Sans, Comic Sans MS, cursive; font-size: 15px; color:blue;  }
  table, th, td {border: 0px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function display_c(){
var refresh=1000; // Refresh rate in milli seconds
mytime=setTimeout('display_ct()',refresh)
}

function display_ct() {
var strcount
var x = new Date()
document.getElementById('ct').innerHTML = x;


tt=display_c();
 }
</script>
<body onload=display_ct();>
<center><header>Kinder App</header></center>
<br>
<center><h1>Kinder App - Add Details</h1></center>

<?php
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1

$storeFolder = 'uploads';   //2

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
  
 $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3

 $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4
  
 $targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5

 move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6
  
}

define ("DB_USER", "root");
define ("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define ("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define ("DB_NAME", "kp2admin");

$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

$moduleId=$_POST["mID"];
$moduleName=$_POST["mName"];
$description=$_POST["mDesc"];
$icon=$_POST["icon"];
$version=$_POST["mVersion"];
$location=$_POST["mLocate"];


$sql = "UPDATE module SET 'Module_Name' = '".$moduleName."', 'Description' = '".$description."', 'Icon' = ".$icon.", 
    'Version' = ".$version.", 'Location' = '".$location."'
  WHERE Module_ID LIKE '".$moduleId."'" ;
echo "<center><div><b>Details Updated.</b></div></center>";

mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
<form name="myform" action="KinderAppAdmin.html" method="POST">
<input type="image" src="/KinderApp/images/sds.png" name="image" width="61" height="49">
</form>

<p align="right"><b><span id='ct' ></span></b></p>
<footer><center>Copyright © All Rights Reserved</center></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what issues you are having with your current code ??

Comment: I am trying to update my database values. However, the current codes I am using is not updating at all even with the SQL command. I am trying to use the Where clause in the statement. I want to update the row only where module ID is the dropdown list selected value. But For my current codes, it doesn't update at all

Comment: Are getting correct value for ModuleID in `edit_file.php` page ?? if possible echo the sql string and check whether it is properly constructed or not ? if you can post sql in comment it might be helpful !

Comment: The value that is in the drop down list was drawn from the database. Now I want to use the selected value. So, the value I am using is correct. And don't mind me for being a noob here... You want me to post the SQL command?

Comment: what i want is `$moduleId=$_POST["mID"]` value for moduleId from select box and value `$sql`

Comment: Ah ok. The values for $moduleId are as follows: http://gyazo.com/81042a5893db7b9d331c202fa8bf58ca

In the drop down list: http://gyazo.com/1685a3909e5e96841cdc5f9e714e62da

Sql Command result: http://gyazo.com/0ff71262af1f5a0f763ed34b18d09004